# Saving a big dataset on a h5 file

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I am trying to create a memory for my machine learning application. The size of memory is `NXz` where `z` is the size of my vector and `N` is the number of it's instances on the memory.  `N` can be very large. I will be reading and updating individual rows as the model training proceeds. Conventionally when creating a dataset using `h5py`, we do,

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((mem_size,zt_size))
with h5py.File("my_file.h5",'w') as hf:            
     hf.create_dataset("my_dset",matrix)
```

But I am worried that if I take a very large `mem_size`, the line, `matrix = np.zeros((mem_size,zt_size))` might fail, as the ram might get filled up. Alternatively, I thought I'll fill up the memory iteratively,

```
 vector = np.zeros((mem_size,zt_size))
 with h5py.File("my_file.h5",'w') as hf:
     for i in range(mem_size):
         hf.create_dataset(str(i),vector)
```

However, now I am worried that reading and updating from the memory will be slower since there are so many indices. How can I go about doing this without filling up my ram or without creating a large relative lag? Will also appreciate alternate implementations using different libraries.

**Note** that I will be using disc memory during the training, so this will perhaps be the bottleneck of my training.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the term "memory" for program data in system RAM and saved on disk. They are different.

You are correct, your program is limited to the amount of data it can hold "in memory" by system RAM. However, a program can access data from the disk (in files) that are much larger than system RAM.

For example, if you have 24GB RAM, your program can probably create a 20GB array in memory (depending on what else your system is doing at the time). You can then write that array to disk (creating a 20GB file). You can then create another 20GB of in memory data and append that to your file (which grows to 40GB). Repeat this many times, and the file gets larger each time. However, your program's memory footprint does not increase (it can't).

When working with large data sets, design your program to access and work with subsets of the data. You can use HDF5 to store your data on disk and numpy/h5py to read data slices into memory. That is a whole topic on it's own.